# Multicore make in parallel rather than "threaded" execution?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

I have a Makefile to execute a test suite that looks roughly like this:

```
%.diff.png: %.test.png
    echo '$*: Comparing with good PNG.'

%.test.png: %.pdf
    echo '$*: Converting PDF to PNG.'

%.pdf: %.tex
    echo '$*: Generating PDF output.'
```

with all the `echo` statements supplemented with the actual tests in the real Makefile.

When I execute all of these tests with `make test` (the `test` target is not shown above), I obviously get linear output:

```
...
umtest200b: Generating PDF output.
umtest200b: Converting PDF to PNG.
umtest200b: Comparing with good PNG.
...
```

When I run these tests with multi-job make (`make -j2 test`, say), the tests are executed in a "threaded" order:

```
...
umtest202a: Generating PDF output.
umtest202b: Generating PDF output.
...
umtest202a: Converting PDF to PNG.
umtest202b: Converting PDF to PNG.
...
umtest202a: Comparing with good PNG.
umtest202b: Comparing with good PNG.
...
```

Perhaps you can see the problem; before discovering if the test fails it's already run through *all* of the PDF generations and PNG conversions for every single other test.

Is there a way to organise the tests so that even when run with multiple jobs the tests are run to completion before moving on to the next test? Or is this a task for a better `make`?

Answer (score 1):

I did some reading on the `-j` flag and I think the issue is that this starts new jobs for **independent rules**. The jobs for every image are independent, so the first dependency for each target will be run like you're seeing.

I think the main problem here is that this task is inherently serial, that's to say that the dependencies for each target must be run *in order, one after another*. So within each target, you don't have a way to take advantage of multiprogramming, *at this level of granularity*.

As `make` doesn't seem to be processing dependencies in the order that you want, perhaps a unit testing framework that supports parallel tests would be a better fit. I know through some Googling that several of these exits, but I can't recommend when as I haven't used any and am not sure which language you're using.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head with "the dependencies for each target must be run in order". I think I was unclear in my question, though; no matter the number of jobs I specify, the entire set of PDFs are generated, then all converted to PNG, then all tested for correctness.

Comment: Strange that the deps would be processed that way. I've updated my answer with some different advice.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the order of execution of targets is explicitly specified, `make` executes them in an *arbitrary* order--both in parallel and in non-parallel mode.  This order undergoes internal algorithms of `make` and in your case yields unpleasant results.

The solution is to impel an explicit ordering to your tests.

From your part of makefile, I assume that there exists an unrevealed "source" variable that contains a list of targets to test (on these targets implicit ones depend).  Also immediate expansion of that variable yields correct results.

Assume the variable's like that:

```
list=file1 file2 file3 ... fileN
```

then, to solve the problem, it would suffice to generate the following dependencies:

```
file2: file1
file3: file2 
...
fileN: fileN-1
run_tests: fileN
```

How should we generate it?  Let's write an foreach-eval loop **after** the `list` variable gets its value:

```
len=$(words $(list))
$(foreach t,                                                  \
   $(join                                                     \ 
      $(addsuffix : ,$(wordlist 2,$(len),$(list)) run_tests), \
      $(list)                                                 \
   )                                                          \
   , $(eval $(t))                                             \
)
```

This will generate a part of makefile just like C preprocessor does (or, more correctly, LISP macros).  It will work like this: for each item `t` in the list formed by `join`ing (concatenating each element of first list with corresponding element of the second) the list `file2 file3 ... fileN run_tests`, to each element of which a suffix `:` is added (thus forming `file2: file3: ... fileN: run_tests:`), with source list `file1 file2 ... fileN`; - for each such item `t` in list with joined elements evaluate it as part of makefile's source, thus acting as the rules shown above were prescribed.

Now you're only to invoke run_tests target and it will go one-by-one.

Comment: I see what you're saying here but I think it needs a little more work:  this approach will fully serialise the processing, negating any gains that could be achieved in parallel. So I think I want `test3: test1`, `test4: test2`, `test5: test3`, and so on. (Hard-coding the number of parallel executions, but that's okay.)

Comment: Just two days ago in my work I encountered the same problem.  What I deduced is that if you want to mix sequential and parallel, you'd better not use `make`.  Assume you adopted the `test3: test1` scheme and `test1` takes 1 hour to finish, while all other tests take 1 hour in total.  Then with such a scheme total execution time will be 50% longer (with 2 parallel jobs).

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly, another idea came into my mind!

```
%.diff.png:
    $(MAKE) $*.test.png
    echo '$*: Comparing with good PNG.'
```

This solves everything except that tests may not be invoked in proper order (but in practice they most likely will go well).